# Error NU1002 The dependency EntityFramework 6.1.3 in project WebApplication1 does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have the community version of VS2015. I can create a console app and build it no problem.  Once I run the package manager and install the entityframework and then build it again it gives me the above error.

I have DNX installed. I have tried to uninstall VS 2015 and reinstall but to no avail. This has happened because I tried to to install MVC boilerplate found a this address: http://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-mvc-boilerplate/ I have since uninstalled it but DNX seems to remain and now I have that error.

It may be a simple fix however I am a beginner at this and cant figure it out. Anyone like to give me a few ideas as to what this is and how to fix it I would be appreciative.

Comment: I think you need to update to EF7, as prior versions of EF don't support PCL.

Comment: Winner. Used "Install-Package EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer –Pre" and it now builds. Thankyou.

Comment: @si2030 I'm getting the same error how did you fix it?  Where did you run that command?

Comment: @erotavlas You can run this in the Package Manager Console. This will appear at the bottom of the VS2015 window along with Output, Error List , Command Window etc. If it is not showing then go to Tools/NeGet Package Manager and click on Package Manager console. This will bring it up.  In there just copy in "Install-Package EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer –Pre". You will also have to add in "Install-Package EntityFramework.Commands -pre" and then go to the Project.json file and under "Commands" add in "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands" under "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel" and rebuild

Comment: I ran the above commands but they did not solve the problem for me. What seems to have solved the problem is running those commands and then deleting the line `"EntityFramework": "6.1.3"` from project.json. Everything builds now, but I can't say with certainty that this won't create more issues.

Answer (score 1):

Replace Entity FrameWork `"EntityFramework": "6.1.3"` with `"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"`.

It work properly then build it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12453326)

Comment: Its a Entity Framework version issue. kindly change it 7.0.0-rc1-final,